# Right pad in DB2 version 8

Tags: db2

In recent versions of DB2 there is the function RPAD to pad strings with a given character up to a given length e.g.

select RPAD(lastname,20,' ') from sample.employee

Unfortunately, it seems that RPAD does not exist in DB2 version 8. Besides defining a user defined function, not very convenient in my case, is there another way to pad a string in DB2 ver. 8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
select left(lastname || repeat(' ', 20), 20) from sample.employee
```